# Xlookup not working in office 365 when trying to search with wildcard

Tags: excel, xlookup

I have data table that looks like this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| ?RFQMNKOIM0K1 | 1 |
| JFFN5KKKK6KYSS | 2 |
| TUFFHHKK$FOJ6I | 3 |
| (2FOA5ZODERTW | 4 |
| ?RFQMNKOM0K1 | 5 |
| ?RFQMGYRTE0K1 | 6 |
| ?RFQMNQ#34K1 | 7 |
| ?RFQM98IKM0K1 | 8 |

and another one that looks like this:

| E |
| --- |
| FQMNKOIM0 |
| FN5KKKK6KY |
| FFHHKK$FOJ |
| FOA5ZODER |
| FQMNKOM0 |
| FQMGYRTE0 |
| FQMNQ#34 |
| FQM98IKM0 |

I'm trying to do xlookup with wildcard, I want to lookup E column values in A and return values in B, formula:

```
=XLOOKUP("*"&E1&"*",A1:B8,B1:B8,,2)
```

but I get a `#value!` error.

How to resolve this? I'm using Office 365.

[image]

Comment: Wildcard is not a problem. lookup_array should be 1 dimensional - A1:A8 instead of A1:B8

Answer (score 1):

Use `XLOOKUP()` in this way.

```
 =XLOOKUP("*"&E1&"*",$A$1:$A$8,$B$1:$B$8,,2)
```

[image]

Comment: Or `A1:B8` if the OP does want to return both columns since that is possible at once

Comment: Not behind a pc to test now but why not lookup all values at once? Surely that's possible.